# Microsoft Access 2010 Date Conversion

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I don't have much experience so I apologize in advance for a potentially dumb question. I did not create these tables nor the queries that have been used in the past. With that said --

For the past several months I have been using a date conversion query that was given to me to update columns from an integer to a date. It used to work just fine and I swear everything is the same for my latest data extractions, but at some point the dates started getting wonky. For example, a typical date column might look like:

```
58222
58158
59076
58103
```

And the conversion query looks something like this:

```
IIf([D_posting]<>0,[D_posting]-18261,0)
```

And returns the above dates as:

```
05/27/2059
03/24/2059
09/27/2061
01/28/2059
```

Which obviously is wrong. The situation kind of reminds me of how I remember we generated random numbers in C++ (which was a long time ago), but for the life of me I can't figure out how to reverse engineer the correct subtraction factor without a reference point.

I also tried using the CDate() function instead, and it resulted in a bunch of future dates also, leading me to wonder if there's something else wrong. I work for a small physicians group so it might be something in the Electronic Health Records software, but I'd like suggestion on what I should check to make sure it's nothing that I've done.

Comment: If your data contains values like '58222', then there must be some date way in the future or someone is playing games with an offset. The value '41925' equates to 10/13/2014. What type of field is [D_posting]?

Comment: Actually, assuming the offset is 18261, then 58222 translates into 5/28/2009. Are the dates you posted AFTER the conversion, or before?

Comment: Wayne, can you tell me what the formula is to convert it to a date? I couldn't find it anywhere. I could look at a previous data extraction and then modify the formula until the new one fits the old one. The dates that I posted are after the conversion.

Comment: I posted an answer with the functions. If the dates you posted are based on the table values, did you subtract the offset? If you already did that then possibly somebody messed up your data?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a query that uses the 'cdate' function (see below) to return the date. You can modify the code so that it subtracts the offset (maybe 18261?)

In the immediate window of VBA you can tinker with the following:

The 'cdate' will take a number and convert it to a date:

```
?cdate(41925)
```

10/13/2014

The 'cdbl' will take a date and convert to a number.

```
?CDbl(Date())
```

41926

Comment: I tried cdate([D_Posting]-18261) and cdate([D_ServiceFrom]-18261) and ended up with this result: http://s27.postimg.org/kf3ce4stf/acess_error.png Isn't it weird that the second column is sometimes 20 years later, and sometimes 9 years later? The two columns should actually match up, or at least be reasonably close together. I don't mind using a different offset for different columns, but seeing as how it's sometimes 20 years and sometimes 9 (within one column) that throws everything off. Crud. Something wonky is definitely afoot.

Comment: Hate to be the bearer of bad news... if you manually convert the first row, it IS 20 years difference! The last row is ~9 years difference.